# Downloading iFramePlayer Video

Tags: javascript, java, html, flash, video

I want to download a video available [here](http://www.yugioh.com/yu-gi-oh/the-heart-of-the-cards/210). Like the top right corner indicates, it might be hosted on [`Crunchyroll`](https://www.crunchyroll.com/) so let's inspect the page source.

This is the html code snippet of interest:

```
<div id="zype_5387dd4269702d063f000000" style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
        <iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" id="_video_5387dd4269702d063f000000" src="https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-88206-hkyj&amp;media_id=663121&amp;video_format=0&amp;video_quality=0&amp;auto_play=0" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" nuan_newframe="true"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inspection reveals that the video is embedded in an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) and indeed is hosted on `Crunchyroll`. It is also important to note that the [src attribute](https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-88206-hkyj&media_id=663121&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0) is the link going directly to the video player page.

On the player page the HTML looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"lang="de" xml:lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.crunchyroll.com/common/static/js/swfobject.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.crunchyroll.com/css//20150727144515.1ae5987b9d8aa2552cc16fb8eadc8e78/crcommon/reset.css"/>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
      }

      #content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
   </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <style type="text/css">
          .clearfix { zoom: 1; /* triggers hasLayout */ display: block; /* resets display for IE/Win */}
          .clearfix {display: inline-block;}  /* for IE/Mac */
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"><div id="the_embedded_player" style="display:block;" ><div style="color:red; text-align:center; margin:16px 0px;">You either have Javascript turned off or an old version of Flash Player.<br/><br/>  <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" rel="nofollow">Get the latest Flash Player</a></div></div><script type="text/javascript"><!--
swfobject.embedSWF("https:\/\/www.crunchyroll.com\/flash\/20150615120132.eb0aab8f716ea6981edb6397bd93ffc3\/StandardVideoPlayer.swf",'the_embedded_player','100%', '100%', '9.0.115','https://www.crunchyroll.com/common/static/flash/express_install.swf',{"config_url":"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crunchyroll.com%2Fxml%2F%3Freq%3DRpcApiVideoPlayer_GetStandardConfig%26media_id%3D663121%26video_format%3D0%26video_quality%3D0%26auto_play%3D0%26aff%3Daf-88206-hkyj%26show_pop_out_controls%3D0%26enable_next%3D0%26lang%3DdeDE"},{"wmode":"transparent","allowFullScreen":"true","allowscriptaccess":"always","allownetworking":"all"},{"id":"the_embedded_player","style":"display:block;"},null);
//--></script></div>
    <!--  pylon16 : c64387480c -->
  </body>
</html>
```

It becomes clear that the video must be a [`swf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) flash video file. `embedSWF` is called which is defined [here](https://www.crunchyroll.com/common/static/js/swfobject.js) and looks like this ([after beautifying](http://jsbeautifier.org/)):

```
embedSWF: function(ab, ah, ae, ag, Y, aa, Z, ad, af, ac) {
    var X = {
        success: false,
        id: ah
    };
    if (M.w3 && !(M.wk && M.wk < 312) && ab && ah && ae && ag && Y) {
        w(ah, false);
        K(function() {
            ae += "";
            ag += "";
            var aj = {};
            if (af && typeof af === r) {
                for (var al in af) {
                    aj[al] = af[al]
                }
            }
            aj.data = ab;
            aj.width = ae;
            aj.height = ag;
            var am = {};
            if (ad && typeof ad === r) {
                for (var ak in ad) {
                    am[ak] = ad[ak]
                }
            }
            if (Z && typeof Z === r) {
                for (var ai in Z) {
                    if (typeof am.flashvars != D) {
                        am.flashvars += "&" + ai + "=" + Z[ai]
                    } else {
                        am.flashvars = ai + "=" + Z[ai]
                    }
                }
            }
            if (F(Y)) {
                var an = u(aj, am, ah);
                if (aj.id == ah) {
                    w(ah, true)
                }
                X.success = true;
                X.ref = an
            } else {
                if (aa && A()) {
                    aj.data = aa;
                    P(aj, am, ah, ac);
                    return
                } else {
                    w(ah, true)
                }
            }
            if (ac) {
                ac(X)
            }
        })
    } else {
        if (ac) {
            ac(X)
        }
    }
}
```

This obfuscated code doesn't look like it's going to lead anywhere.

Copying and pasting each of the links found in the html into the browser doesn't seem to allow downloading the video (idea taken from [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Download-SWF-Files)). How do I get the correct url?

Note:
The programming code for downloading the video file is not the main focus here, but I would use [this](http://jsoup.org/) for html parsing and [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File)) for download the file.